# Nested Select in LINQ with Lambda Expression

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have two sequence of objects; namely `Messages` for `Message` object and `Newsflashes` for `Newsflash` object.

Both are derived through Entity Framework ADO.NET Entity Model. The diagram of the model is as below:
[image]

As you can see, the `Newsflash` inherits from `Message`. However, the generated Index in the controller somehow error and I need to do manual query to pass the right sequence to the View.

The `Newsflash` table only has one column, which is Id and at the same time a foreign key to the `Message` Id.
I want to query like this in LINQ `SELECT * FROM MESSAGE WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM NEWSFLASH)`

So far I have tried something like this:
`var message = Messages.Where(x => x.Id == Newsflash.Any(y=>y.Id))`

But I am getting error that cannot convert int to bool. What did I do wrong? How do nested select especially from a list is handled in LINQ? How can I access element in the sequence; in this case `Newsflash` so that I could get the Id individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any returns a bool, not a list of values.  If you want a list of Newsflash ID's, you would use `Newsflash.Select(x => x.Id)`

To get your list of messages that have a newsflash, you should use:

```
var messages = (from m in Messages
                join n in Newsflash on m.Id equals n.Id
                select m).ToList();
```

This will join messages to your newsflash based on the Id for each, and then select the Message object that matches.

alternative lamba syntax:

```
var messages = Messages.Join(Newsflash, x => x.Id, y => y.Id, (x, y) => new { Message = x }).ToList();
```

Comment: If I were to do it using the lambda expression thingy, how should I do it?

Comment: I tried `var messages = db.Messages.Select(x=> x.Id).Intersect(db.Newsflashes.Select(y=>y.Id));` but it returned `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]` instead of the sequence of `Message`. What should I do to get the whole object instead of `Id` field only?

Comment: `db.Messages.Join(db.Newsflashes, x => x.Id, y => y.Id, (x, y) => x).ToList()`  this will return all matching messages objects

Answer (score 2):

If newsflash is just a list of Ids Try this.

```
var message = Messages.Where(x => Newsflash.Contains(x.Id));
```

or

```
var message = Messages.Where(x => Newsflash.Select(y => y).Contains(x.Id));
```

simple example.

```
var listOfInts = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
var listOfInts2 = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};

listOfInts.Where(x => listOfInts2.Contains(x));
```

Comment: Awesome. I will use this reference in the future! +1